# Загрузка файла, phpexcel

Tags: php

Загружаю файл, который генерирует файл в формате.xsl , но функция

`$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);`

возвращает значение - `CSV`. Если пересохранить файл вручную, функция возвращает значение - `Excel5`. Как можно его конвертировать через php в формат `Excel5` ?

```
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    //$objReader->setDelimiter(',');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
    die('Error');
}

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$flag = true;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    if ($row == 1) {
        continue;
    }

    print_r($rowData);
}
```

В переменной $rowData - не корректные значения с неправильной кодировкой. Если загружаю файл в формате .ods , или пересохраняю файл - все норм

Comment: Вы тут используете какие то сторонние библиотеки видимо. Какие?

Comment: Только библиотеку PHPExcel_IOFactory

Comment: Наверное это будет откровением, но подавляющее большинство присутствующих здесь никогда не слышало о какой-то библиотеке, скаченной вами с гитхаба. Не проще ли задать вопрос разработчику этой библиотеки?

Comment: Ну не думаю. Кто работает с php , думаю не раз стыкался с задачей импорта ексель файла, и работал с этой библиотекой -https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel